# Get the total Count of down line record using SQL Server CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

How to Sum all down-line to their immediate up-line using SQL.

- All Staff Sales are the Sales of Supervisor.
- All Supervisor Sales are the Sales of Manager.
- All Manager Sales are the Sales of Head.

Current data:

```
ID   Name     Role            Level      Reportingto     Sales
---------------------------------------------------------------
1    Joe      Head              1          NULL           0
2    Smith    Manager           2           1             0
3    Mike     Supervisor        3           2             0
4    Mitch    Staff             4           3             10
5    Jen      Staff             4           3             20
6    Ian      Manager           2           1             0
7    Jess     Supervisor        3           6             0
8    Rocky    Staff             4           7             5
9    Jessica  Supervisor        3           6             0
10   Rolly    Staff             4           9             3
```

Ideal output

```
ID   Name     Role            Level      Reportingto     Sales
---------------------------------------------------------------
1    Joe      Head              1          NULL           38
2    Smith    Manager           2           1             30
3    Mike     Supervisor        3           2             30
4    Mitch    Staff             4           3             10
5    Jen      Staff             4           3             20
6    Ian      Manager           2           1             8
7    Jess     Supervisor        3           6             5
8    Rocky    Staff             4           7             5
9    Jessica  Supervisor        3           6             3
10   Rolly    Staff             4           9             3
```

I'm using SQL Server 2016

Comment: SQL Server 2016

Comment: i think the expected results should be 38 for rows 2,3 and 8 for row 7 based on your logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,Name varchar(25),Role varchar(25),Level int,Reportingto int,Sales int)
Insert into @YourTable values 
(1    ,'Joe'      ,'Head'              ,1           ,NULL          ,0),
(2    ,'Smith'    ,'Manager'           ,2           ,1             ,0),
(3    ,'Mike'     ,'Supervisor'        ,3           ,2             ,0),
(4    ,'Mitch'    ,'Staff'             ,4           ,3             ,10),
(5    ,'Jen'      ,'Staff'             ,4           ,3             ,20),
(6    ,'Ian'      ,'Manager'           ,2           ,1             ,0),
(7    ,'Jess'     ,'Supervisor'        ,3           ,6             ,0),
(8    ,'Rocky'    ,'Staff'             ,4           ,7             ,5),
(9    ,'Jessica'  ,'Supervisor'        ,3           ,6             ,0),
(10   ,'Rolly'    ,'Staff'             ,4           ,9             ,3)


Declare @Top int = null --<<  Sets top of Hier Try 6

;with cteP as (
      Select Seq  = cast(10000+Row_Number() over (Order by Name) as varchar(500))
            ,ID
            ,Reportingto 
            ,Lvl=1
            ,Name 
            ,Role
            ,Sales
      From   @YourTable 
      Where  IsNull(@Top,-1) = case when @Top is null then isnull(Reportingto ,-1) else ID end
      Union  All
      Select Seq  = cast(concat(p.Seq,'.',10000+Row_Number() over (Order by r.Name)) as varchar(500))
            ,r.ID
            ,r.Reportingto 
            ,p.Lvl+1
            ,r.Name 
            ,r.Role
            ,r.Sales
      From   @YourTable r
      Join   cteP p on r.Reportingto  = p.ID)
Select A.ID
      ,A.Name
      ,A.Role
      ,A.Lvl
      ,A.Reportingto 
      ,Sales  = (Select sum(Sales) from cteP where  Seq Like A.Seq+'%')
    From cteP A
    Order By A.Seq
```

**Returns**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `outer apply`.

```
select t1.id,t1.name,t1.role,t1.level,t1.reportingto,coalesce(t2.sales,t1.sales) as val
from t t1
outer apply (select sum(sales) as sales
             from t t2 
             where t1.id<=t2.id and t1.level<t2.level) t2
```

Comment: I think the reason the top three aren't all 38 is that Ian is a manager that reports directly to Joe, so his 8 sales don't count for Smith/Mike's totals.

Comment: @HartCO .. based on the op's explanation, i interpreted it as *sales of all rows < a given id and whose levels are greater than the current row's level should be summed up*

Comment: Understandable, I thought that at first until I noticed the op's expected results do line up with the recursive approach.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a simpler way to do this, but it seems to me like you need to start at the 'staff' and recurse up:

```
;with cte as (SELECT [ID], [Name], [Role], [Level], [Reportingto], [Sales], Sales as Sum_Sales
              FROM #Table1 
              WHERE [Role] = 'Staff'
              UNION ALL
              SELECT a.[ID], a.[Name], a.[Role], a.[Level], a.[Reportingto], a.[Sales], a.Sales + b.Sum_Sales AS Sum_Sales
              FROM #Table1 a
              JOIN cte b
                 ON b.Reportingto = a.ID
              )
SELECT [ID], [Name], [Role], [Level], [Reportingto],SUM(Sum_Sales) as Sales
FROM cte
GROUP BY [ID], [Name], [Role], [Level], [Reportingto]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the table as KTemp I created a new column. Hope this helps.

```
 SELECT *,
           CASE
               WHEN LEVEL=1 THEN
                      (SELECT sum(Sales)
                       FROM KTemp x
                       WHERE x.Level IN (1,
                                         2,
                                         3,
                                         4) )
               WHEN LEVEL=2 THEN
                      (SELECT sum(Sales)
                       FROM KTemp x
                       WHERE x.Level IN (2,
                                         3,
                                         4) )
               WHEN LEVEL=3 THEN
                      (SELECT sum(Sales)
                       FROM KTemp x
                       WHERE x.Level IN (3,
                                         4) )
               WHEN LEVEL=4 THEN
                      (SELECT sum(Sales)
                       FROM KTemp x
                       WHERE x.Level IN (4) )
           END AS [Up-line Sales]
    FROM KTemp
```